# error while loading geo location based invocations in wso2

Tags: wso2, analytics

I configured geo location based statistics according to the [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/analyzing-apim-statistics-with-batch-analytics/using-geo-location-based-statistics/configuring-geo-location-based-statistics/) for api manager and in the analytics dashboard i added the "GEO LOCATION BASED INVOCATIONS" widget.but when i select the api name it stuck and does not load anything:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwL8z.png)

also in the dashboard console i got the following error:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.data.provider.endpoint.DataProviderEndPoint} - Error found in method : io.siddhi.query.compiler.exception.SiddhiParserException: Error between @ Line: 1. Position: 0 and @ Line: 1. Position: 109. Syntax error in SiddhiQL, no viable alternative at input '{{timeFrom}}'.
```

[2020-10-04 22:32:49,883] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.data.provider.endpoint.DataProviderEndPoint} - Error initializing the data provider endpoint for source type SiddhiStoreDataProvider. Error between @ Line: 1. Position: 0 and @ Line: 1. Position: 109. Syntax error in SiddhiQL, no viable alternative at input '{{timeFrom}}'. io.siddhi.query.compiler.exception.SiddhiParserException: Error between @ Line: 1. Position: 0 and @ Line: 1. Position: 109. Syntax error in SiddhiQL, no viable alternative at input '{{timeFrom}}'

FYI i called the api with 'X-Forwarded-For' header and the value is my public ip : 5.237.24.12

can someone help me **please**?
for 5 days i have been trying for this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a new dashboard or adding this widget to an existing dashboard make sure to add the "Date Time Range" widget to the current page if it is not. Then subscribe "GEO LOCATION BASED INVOCATIONS" widget to the "Date Time Range" widget.
"Date Time Range" provide the time durations to the other widgets. Looks like it failed due to lack of this widget.